# When i try to do react popout example its not working

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to do this example of react popout but it doesn't seem to be working.

https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/react-popout#readme

example is at the bottom.

```
import React from "react"
import Popout from "react-popout"

class PopupLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.popout = this.popout.bind(this);
    this.popoutClosed = this.popoutClosed.bind(this);
    this.state = { isPoppedOut: false };
  }

  popout() {
    this.setState({isPoppedOut: true});
  }

  popoutClosed() {
    this.setState({isPoppedOut: false});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isPoppedOut) {
      return (
        <Popout title='Window title' onClosing={this.popoutClosed}>
          <div>Popped out content!</div>
        </Popout>
      );
    } else {
      var popout = <span onClick={this.popout} className="buttonGlyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
      return (
        <div>
          <strong>Section {popout}</strong>
          <div>Inline content</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default PopupLogin
```

This is supposed to look like http://jake.ginnivan.net/react-popout/ this.
But in my output looks like this. [image: react-popout supposed output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a text to the span ,according to their docs, so as a result there was no link, hence no onClick was fired. You could style the link as per your needs

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-vxtu9

```
import React from "react";
import Popout from "react-popout";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class PopupLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.popout = this.popout.bind(this);
    this.popoutClosed = this.popoutClosed.bind(this);
    this.state = { isPoppedOut: false };
  }

  popout() {
    this.setState({ isPoppedOut: true });
  }

  popoutClosed() {
    this.setState({ isPoppedOut: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isPoppedOut) {
      return (
        <Popout
          url="popout.html"
          title="Window title"
          onClosing={this.popoutClosed}
        >
          <div>Popped out content!</div>
        </Popout>
      );
    } else {
      var popout = (
        <span
          onClick={this.popout}
          className="buttonGlyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-export"
        >
          Open
        </span>
      );
      return (
        <div>
          <strong>Section {popout}</strong>
          <div>Inline content</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<PopupLogin />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: yeah that worked. Also is there any alternative to this functionality?

Comment: @Gthu Alternative as in?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code in documentation missing the text. Add `(pop window out)` in the **popout**.

```
import React from "react";
import Popout from "react-popout";

class PopupLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.popout = this.popout.bind(this);
    this.popoutClosed = this.popoutClosed.bind(this);
    this.state = { isPoppedOut: false };
  }

  popout() {
    this.setState({ isPoppedOut: true });
  }

  popoutClosed() {
    this.setState({ isPoppedOut: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isPoppedOut) {
      return (
        <Popout title="Window title" onClosing={this.popoutClosed}>
          <div>Popped out content!</div>
        </Popout>
      );
    } else {
      var popout = (
        <span
          onClick={this.popout}
          className="buttonGlyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-export"
        >
          <a
            style={{
              textDecoration: "underline",
              color: "blue",
              cursor: "pointer"
            }}
            onClick={this.popout}
          >
            (pop window out)
          </a>
        </span>
      );
      return (
        <div>
          <strong>Section {popout}</strong>
          <div>Inline content</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default PopupLogin;
```